# How do I get the attached file list from the space?

Tags: google-workspace, google-chat

According to [Chat API](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/v1/messages/list?hl=en), I can get messages and check if a file is attached. But I cannot find the API to get the attachment list even though I can see the files in "Files" tab in the space.

Is it possible to get the list of attached files from the messages with API?

[Attachments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SslcH.png)

I got the messages and check if the message has an attachment property 1 by 1. In order to show the file list, I added it to a temporary list. If the messages are too much, it will take more time and it's not efficient. I hope there is a special API to get a list of all attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently, there is no API available to retrieve a list of files in Google Chat spaces

It appears that you have already requested this feature in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/293487572). However, in my opinion, it is possible that this API may never be realized due to security and privacy concerns. But I remain hopeful that Google will find a solution that addresses any security concerns.